# How safe is Raid 0 with Perc710P hardware raid controller?

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, hardware-raid

I bought my new server Dell R620 and it does have Perc710P HW Raid controller.

I have 4x512GB Samsung 850 Pro SSD's.

I will use cPanel and host over 1000 websites on server. That means I need storage space and speed. I know that Raid 0 is not safe. But what about making Raid 0 with hardware raid controller? Does it make it difference or still unsafe to use Raid 0?

Answer (score 6):

Regardless of how RAID 0 is implemented it works the same way, it does not include fault tolerance. If a disk fails you will loose access to the RAID 0 volume. If you want fault tolerance for your volumes then you should use RAID 1, RAID 5 etc.

here is a link that the describes the different RAID levels:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/raid-levels-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if a RAID0 is hardware or software based. All implications and pros and cons about performance and probability of losing a disk stay the same. Losing a disk also depends on the disks itself and could also occur if there is a bad cable or cable connection.

In case of a disk failure and using RAID0, all data would be destroyed instantly which would make the 1000 websites offline.
Depending on the backup/restore strategy it might be feasible to run a RAID0, still at a very high risk.

Answer (score 1):

Hard raid (with BBU) only makes a difference when it comes a power outage and your ups (if any) can't keep the server up, and the power goes down; if there's a bbu the controller and disks will stay up enough to have the writing committed to disks, and that prevents data loss/corruption in case of power failure, and REGARDLESS of the raid level.
Coming to your question, consider that **NOTHING** can be considered **safe** when talking about data security; just imagine how can be considered a raid level that doesn't even implement any kind of redundancy.

Any media failure=All data loss

I won't use such in a production env, consider buying more disks and going to raid10 if you really need raid0 enhanced IO performance. Consider testing raid5 and/or raid1, your SSDs should perform very well even with no raid0. With raid5 you will have 512G less (1,5T more or less) but will have implemented a minmum layer of media fault tolerance.

Will it be **safe** then? No, you will be *more safe*. 
You can never say data are safe, just more or less safe than before.